# Fatal Error on using $exception variable in render() Method in App\Exceptions\Handler.php

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and have an Issue regarding the Handler.php File.

I am trying to create a class that takes an exceptions and transforms it into a JSON Response.
Sadly though, upon calling the constructor a series of Errors are thrown:
(ErrorErrorErrorErrorErrorErrorErrorErrorErrorErrorErrorSymfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError)

My code:
render() in Handler.php:

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    $errorResource = new ErrorResource($exception);
    return $errorResource->getJsonResponse();
}
```

class ErrorResource in ErrorResource.php:

```
<?php

namespace Transformers;

use Throwable;

class ErrorResource
{
    private $exception;

    private $defaultCodes = [TypeError::class => 400];

    private $defaultMessages = [TypeError::class => 'Untgültige URL Parameter'];

    function __construct(Throwable $exception)
    {
        $this->exception = $exception;
    }

    public function getJsonResponse($exception)
    {
        $codeToThrow = 500;
        $messageToThrow = "Internal Server Error";
        $type = get_class($this->exception);

        if (empty($exception->getCode())) {
            $codeToThrow = $this->defaultCodes[$type];
        } else {
            $codeToThrow = $exception->getCode();
        }
        if (empty($exception->getMessage())) {
            $messageToThrow = $this->defaultMessages[$type];
        } else {
            $messageToThrow = $exception->getMessage();
        }
        return response()->json(array(
            'Type' => $type,
            'Message' => $messageToThrow
        ), $codeToThrow);
    }

}
```

I have also tried to move the method getJsonResponse() to the Handler.php file and call it from there, but without any luck.
I am really confused as to why I am not allowed to do certain things with the $exception variable (I have also tried to create a clone of this object - but the same error occures)

I hope you can help me resolving this issue,

Greetins,

Franz

Comment: you just need `return json_encode($exception)`

Comment: please post the exception that you can find on the Logs, because has a lot more informations

Comment: The problem with doing something like this is that if there's an error in your `ErrorResource` it will throw a new exception which will call `ErrorResource` which will throw a new exception and (I can copy-paste this more but you get the idea). Wrap your  `getJsonResponse` and just log the exception you get without re-throwing it to prevent this recursion. Then check your log for what's actually wrong in your code (at first glance it might be `$this->defaultCodes[$type]` when `$type` is not in that array)

Comment: @apokryfos Everything is fine with my code (at least reagarding the issues you mentioned). No Exception in the method getJsonResponse() is thrown, because the code throws an Exception, when calling the constructor.

Comment: @Berto99 - Thank you for pointing out, that laravel provides a log - I didn't know that. Here is the Exception that occures, when calling the constructor([2020-06-13 19:46:25] local.ERROR: Trying to clone an uncloneable object of class TypeError {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Trying to clone an uncloneable object of class TypeError at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\TNT_Homepage\\TNT-Backend_v2\\app\\Exceptions\\Handler.php:70)
[stacktrace]). I think that when calling the constructor, php is trying to clone the object, resulting in the error.

Comment: @Facecube yes, instead of `Throwable $exception` you have to use `Throwable& $exception` os that the object is not copied but instead passed by reference (i mean in the constructor)

Comment: If there's an exception thrown in `render` then it will re-call the exception handler. Probably wise to wrap it in a try-catch regardless

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that PHP is call by value. That is why it is implicitely trying to clone an unclonable object -> Error. To resolve this issue one can use wrapper objects, but I decided to simply use call by reference (https://www.javatpoint.com/php-call-by-reference)